# Image recognition on OpenCV java

Tags: java, opencv, face-recognition

i need some help with ideas about how to change a recognized face throug a webcam, but instead of make a rectangle around the face i need to put an image for example a meme, or something else, rigth now i already can recognize a face and the code put a rectangle but i dont want that, i want to change the face for something else.
i have this code

```
for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
Core.rectangle(imagen, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y      +     rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));

     }
```

and i have the image loaded like this:

```
Mat image2 = Highgui.imread("/índice.jpg");
```

i've found examples in C# but i need java so please if you can help me. =)

Comment: Damm easy Just set label with ImageIcon at the place of rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one thing.

```
Point center =  new Point(rect.x, rect.y);
```

Now use this points to set image at the location with center.x and center.y.

Eg.

```
label.setLocation((int) center.x, (int) center.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
    Core.rectangle(imagen, new Point(rect.x, rect.y),
        new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
        new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
```